# not receiving full json string

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, postman

I have written an API in MVC - all work OK until the JSON being passed across is long.

It was failing when being called from another web project and also when using Postman

So I added the following to the web.config.

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="204800000" executionTimeout="7200" />
```

Now when I run it through Postman - it works every time - no matter the length I send across.

But ... when called from my web project, it still fails - chopping off the data

Comment: Here is how I call it from within my web project

var MAPackage = {
   transmissionTime: sdate + ' ' + stime,
   userID: loginDetails.resourceID,
   jsonData: JSON.stringify(jsonText)
};

$.post("server/api/upload", MAPackage)
.done(function (results) {
 alert("all done");
})

Comment: Is your client web project running into timeouts? You could use `jQuery.ajaxSetup()` to set it in beforhand.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with the Json serializer you are using in your client application & request time out.